# Overlaying rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2, greatest-n-per-group

So, I want to store sets of key-value pairs in a database and then retrieve a combined set of the key-value pairs based on a series of sets.  Each set might not be complete.

Let's say we have a table as follows:

```
create table MYTABLE (ROLE VARCHAR(62), KEY VARCHAR(62), VALUE VARCHAR(62));
insert into MYTABLE values('R1', 'K1', 'R1K1');
insert into MYTABLE values('R1', 'K2', 'R1K2');
insert into MYTABLE values('R1', 'K3', 'R1K3');
insert into MYTABLE values('R2', 'K1', 'R2K1');
insert into MYTABLE values('R2', 'K2', 'R2K2');
insert into MYTABLE values('R2', 'K4', 'R2K4');
insert into MYTABLE values('R3', 'K1', 'R3K1');
insert into MYTABLE values('R3', 'K4', 'R3K4');
insert into MYTABLE values('R3', 'K5', 'R3K5');
insert into MYTABLE values('R4', 'K1', 'R4K1');
insert into MYTABLE values('R5', 'K6', 'R5K6');
```

I want the following results when given the sequence R1, R2, R3 (or R3, R2, R1 depending on your perspective):

```
+-----+-------+
| KEY | VALUE |
+-----+-------+
| K1  | R3K1  |
| K2  | R2K2  |
| K3  | R1K3  |
| K4  | R3K4  |
| K5  | R3K5  |
+-----+-------+
```

Originally, I was going to do this outside of SQL by retrieving each set and dumping the results into a hash and letting the subsequent items overwrite the previous items:

```
select KEY,VALUE from MYTABLE where ROLE = 'R1';
select KEY,VALUE from MYTABLE where ROLE = 'R2';
select KEY,VALUE from MYTABLE where ROLE = 'R3';
```

But I didn't want to go back to the database for each role if there could be many roles to mix-in.

Eventually I figured out these statements would work:

```
Oracle/DB2:
select distinct KEY, first_value(VALUE) over (partition by KEY order by decode(ROLE, 'R1', 1, 'R2', 2, 'R3', 3) desc) value from MYTABLE where ROLE in ('R1', 'R2', 'R3') order by KEY;
MySQL (guess):
select distinct KEY, first_value(VALUE) over (partition by KEY order by field(ROLE, 'R1, 'R2', 'R3') desc) value from MYTABLE where ROLE in ('R1', 'R2', 'R3') order by KEY;
```

(The "order by KEY" at the end isn't strictly necessary for my need.)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could express that logic with `row_number()`:

```
select key, value
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by key order by role) as rn
    from mytable t
    where role in ('R1', 'R2', 'R3')
) t
where rn = 1
```

The conditional ordering is not really needed here, since `'R1' < 'R2' < 'R3'`. But if you wanted to do that for some other sequence, you would typically use a standard `case` expression:

```
select key, value
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by key 
            order by case role when 'R1' then 1 when 'R2' then 2 when 'R3' then 3 end
        ) as rn
    from mytable t
    where role in ('R1', 'R2', 'R3')
) t
where rn = 1
```

This is a rather portable syntax, that would work in many datatabases (as long as they support window functions).

Comment: You have two changes here: 1) using row_number() instead of distinct...first_value(), and 2) using order by case instead of order by decode/field.  It seems that first_value() is common to DB2, MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server (since 2012), but "case" is definitely more portable.  That said, I think I'll do some EXPLAINs to see if distinct...first_value() has any advantage over row_number().